# live overclocking/overvolting in Linux

Tags: linux

Some motherboards include Windows software that allows overclocking/overvolting the CPU while the computer is booted. How does this work? I'm looking to write a program to implement this functionality for Linux.

Comment: By "implement" do you mean "write" or "download, install, and properly configure"?

Comment: By "implement", I mean "write". What interface does the motherboard expose to the operating system to allow this?

Comment: Also, Stack Overflow seems increasingly close-happy for legitimate questions these days.

Comment: I very much doubt there's a standard API for this across different manufacturers, or that you're going to find any documentation at all. Your best bet would be to try and dig through the Windows code to see how it does it or contact the board manufacturer to see if they're willing to give you documentation.

Comment: Heh, one person even voted to close for being 'off topic'/'not a programming question'. @Rup, thanks for the advice. I had expected that there would be some proprietary magic in communicating with each board.

Comment: @Delan: Agreed.  It's because of an asymmetry - it's impossible to vote "No, don't close" until it's actually been closed.  The best you can do is leave a comment.

Comment: @Delan: I was the first to mark it off-topic (belongs on superuser where people could recommend existing apps), sorry about that.  Only afterward did I realize that another possible reading of the question would involve programming.  I have no idea how two previous people thought this was not a real question though.  And close votes can't be revoked (although they can be reversed).

Comment: @Delan Azanai Perhaps http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_Dynamic_Frequency_Scaling will provide a starting-point. It appears that at least some of this support is built into the Kernel. Good luck.

Comment: If this happens in the future, you can flag for moderator attention. We can close with some non-migrating reason and then reopen. Or, after the fact, we can unlock, reopen, and clear the migration history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method will be chipset/BIOS-specific.  On recent-era systems, it's likely that ACPI is used - so, start by examining the ACPI DSDT of the system of interest.  Try correlating the device IDs / names from the DSDT against strings found in the binary utility to narrow down the device(s) you need.

The LWN.net article [Writing an ACPI driver - an introduction](http://lwn.net/Articles/367630/) has some good background information you'll need.

Comment: Thanks. I was really looking for where to start, and you answered exactly that.